# Pandas Dataframe Getting a count of semi-unique values from columns in a CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I don't think my title accurately conveys my question but I struggled on it for a bit.
I have a range of CSV files. These files contain column names and values. My current code works exactly as I want it to, in that it groups the data by time and then gets me a count of uses per hour and revenue per hour.
However I now want to refine this, in my CSV there is a column name called Machine Name. Each value in this column is unique, but they share the same naming scheme. They can either be Dryer #39 or Dryer #38 or Washer #1 or Washer #12. What I want is to get a count of Dryers and Washers used per hour and I do not care what number washer or dryer it was. Just that it was a washer or dryer.

Here is my code.

```
    for i in range(1): # len(csvList))
    df = wr.s3.read_csv(path=[f's3://{csvList[i].bucket_name}/{csvList[i].key}']) 
    df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
    df = df.groupby(df['Timestamp'].dt.floor('h')).agg( 
    machines_used_per_hour=('Machine Name', 'count'),
    revenue_per_hour=('Total Revenue', 'sum')
    ).reset_index() # Reset the index for the timestamp column 

    for j in df.iterrows():
        dbInsert = """INSERT INTO `store-machine-use`(store_id, timestamp, machines_used_per_hour, revenue_per_hour, notes) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
        values = (int(storeNumberList[i]), str(j[1]['Timestamp']), int(j[1]['machines_used_per_hour']), int(j[1]['revenue_per_hour']),'')
        cursor.execute(dbInsert, values)
        cnx.commit()
```

This data enters the database and looks like:

> store_id, Timestamp, machines_used_per_hour, revenue_per_hour, notes
> 10, 2021-08-22 06:00:00, 4, 14, Test

I want to get an individual count of the types of machines used every hour, in the case of my example it would look like:

> store_id, Timestamp, machines_used_per_hour, revenue_per_hour, washers_per_hour, dryers_per_hour, notes
> 10, 2021-08-22 06:00:00, 4, 14, 1, 3,  Test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cout use [pd.Series.str.startswith](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) and then sum in the aggregation:

```
df['is_dryer'] = df['Machine Name'].startswith('Dryer')
df['is_washer'] = df['Machine Name'].startswith('Washer')

df = df.groupby(df['Timestamp'].dt.floor('h')).agg( 
    machines_used_per_hour=('Machine Name', 'count'),
    revenue_per_hour=('Total Revenue', 'sum'),
    washers_per_hour=('is_washer', 'sum'),
    dryers_per_hour=('is_dryer', 'sum')
).reset_index() # Reset the index for the timestamp column
```

note that if you need more complex pattern matching for determining which machine belongs to which category, you can use regexes with [pd.Series.str.match](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html)

### example

for instance with some fake data, if I have:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(
    {"machine": ["Dryer #1", "Dryer #2", "Washer #43", "Washer #89", "Washer #33"],
    "aggregation_key": [1, 2, 1, 2, 2]}
)
```

after creating the boolean columns with

```
dataframe["is_dryer"]  = dataframe.machine.str.startswith("Dryer")
dataframe["is_washer"]  = dataframe.machine.str.startswith("Washer")
```

dataframe will be

```
      machine  aggregation_key  is_dryer  is_washer
0    Dryer #1                1      True      False
1    Dryer #2                2      True      False
2  Washer #43                1     False       True
3  Washer #89                2     False       True
4  Washer #33                2     False       True
```

and then aggregation gives you what you want:

```
dataframe.groupby(dataframe["aggregation_key"]).agg( 
    washers_per_hour=('is_washer', 'sum'),
    dryers_per_hour=('is_dryer', 'sum')
).reset_index()
```

result will be

```
   aggregation_key  washers_per_hour  dryers_per_hour
0                1                 1                1
1                2                 2                1
```

Comment: This worked exactly as I needed it to and you presented it in a manner that I was able to follow and understand. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex to replace the common machine number identifier pattern to create a `machine_type` series which you can then use to aggregate on.

`df['Machine Type'] = df['Machine Name'].str.replace(' #[0-9]', '', regex=True)`

you can then group on the `Machine Type`

```
df = df.groupby(df['Timestamp'].dt.floor('h')).agg( 
    machines_used_per_hour=('Machine Type', 'count'),
    revenue_per_hour=('Total Revenue', 'sum')
    ).reset_index()
```